# Contextual Binding with Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Is it possible to get Windsor to return different implementations of a service based on a seperate parameter?

For example, if I have a User object which has a Role property, I would like to be able to hydrate this object differently according the the value of Role. I would like to use an IUserService to do this, but have the concrete implementation of IUserService determined by the IoC container.

I think that Ninject offers this functionality as "Contextual Binding" but I'm not sure if Windsor offers it without rolling my own resolution logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible (yet).
Take a look [here](http://castle.uservoice.com/pages/16605-official-castle-project-feedback-forum/suggestions/173776-add-convention-over-configuration-features-to-ioc-containers) and [here](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/04/09/convention-based-dependency-injection-with-castle-microkernelwindsor.aspx).
For now take a look at HandlerProvider if it's got what you need.
If not, you may need to use ISubDependencyResolver (which is not very complicated actually).

Comment: I ended up using the ISubDependencyResolver - it works great! Thanks